# How to use Google idToken, accessToken from my hosted server into my app?

Tags: swift, google-calendar-api, access-token, gidsignin

Forgive me for my English!

I am using google Rest API client and GIDSignIn to sign in google account for my app.

```
     GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = scopes
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()

  func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
              withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            showAlert(title: "Authentication Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
            self.service.authorizer = nil
        } else {

            self.service.authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
           print("Successs")
        }
    }
```

Successfully signed in after using this.

But I want to use idToken and accessToken into my app getting from my hosted server.

By using those token I want to fetch google calendar events.

Please help how can I use tokens which are getting from my hosted server into my iOS app.

Thanks.

Comment: If need more explanation please let me know.

Comment: Try checking this documentation regarding [Google Sign-in for iOS : Authenticate with a backend server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth) to be guided how to communicate with your mobile device and your server.